# Django Rest Framework user authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code.

I am using the django rest framework.

I basically want to allow users to register. 
I send email address, password, username by POST.

I just feel like I am not using the django rest framework correctly.

Can you guys please help me with the code below?

What's the best way to structure it to adhere to the django rest framework principles?

Also, what is the form below is invalid ... How do I post an error message back?

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def user_login(request):

profile = request.POST

if ('id' not in profile or 'email_address' not in profile or 'oauth_secret' not in profile):
    return Response(
        status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

identifier = profile['id']
email_address = profile['email_address']
oauth_secret = profile['oauth_secret']

firstname = None
if 'first_name' in profile:
    firstname = profile['first_name']

lastname = None
if 'last_name' in profile:
    lastname = profile['last_name']

bio = None
if 'bio' in profile:
    bio = profile['bio']

oauth_token = None
if 'oauth_token' in profile:
    oauth_token = profile['oauth_token']

investor = None
if 'investor' in profile:
    investor = profile['investor']

user_form = dict()
user_form['username'] = 'l' + identifier
user_form['password1'] = oauth_secret
user_form['password2'] = oauth_secret
user_form['email'] = email_address

photo = None
noConnections = 0

if 'pictureUrl' in profile:
    photo = profile['pictureUrl']

if 'numConnections' in profile:
    noConnections = profile['numConnections']

try:
    user = User.objects.get(username=identifier)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    serializer = UserRegisterSerializer(data=user_form)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        user = serializer.save()

        user.first_name = firstname
        user.last_name = lastname
        user.save()

        # Save our permanent token and secret for later.
        userprofile = user.get_profile()
        userprofile.bio = bio
        userprofile.photo = photo
        userprofile.no_linked_con = noConnections
        userprofile.oauth_token = oauth_token
        userprofile.oauth_secret = oauth_secret
        userprofile.save()
    else:
        return Response(
            serializer.errors,
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

user = authenticate(username=identifier, password=oauth_secret)
login(request, user)

if not investor:
    send_mail(
        'Please complete your startup profile',
        'Here is the message.',
        'from@example.com',
        list(email_address))

serializer = UserSerializer(user)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading the Django documentation on [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/).  You can create a class for all your form fields and Django will create an HTML form from it, parse the POST parameters, and help with the error messages.

Answer (score -1):

```
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serilaizers.EmailField()
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=255) # max_length is optional if you give it validate the length of character's set
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, write_only=True)

    def validate(attrs): # attrs is dictionary such as {'email':'example@m.com', 'username':'tom', 'password': 'test_password'}
        # process your required validation here such as checking unique, etc
        return attrs

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        instance = User(**validated_data)
        instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save() # before saving you can do any data manipulation
        return instance
```

in view:

```
serializer = UserRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True/False)
serializer.save()
return Response(serilaizer.data, status.201) # here you should import Response and status from rest-framework path and you can return anything
```